# InfoPath silent printing using windows service does not work

Tags: c#, printing, windows-services, console-application, infopath

I have a windows service that prints InfoPath form's default view using the `xdocument.PrintOut()` function. It works on several machine configurations except one case. It does not work on some machines running Windows 2012 (and Win2012R2) (x64), SharePoint 2013 (x64), and Office professional plus 2013 (x86). I am not sure if SharePoint has anything to do with the issue.

Here is what's happening when I checked the difference on the process monitor logs.

When executed as a windows service and `xdocument.PrintOut()` is called, it launches `INFOPATH.EXE` in background, sends print command, initiates the spoolsv.exe (Printer Spooler), printer spooler detects the default printer and nothing happens afterwards.

When the same code is executed using console app, similer set of events happen and in addition it creates spooler files at "`C:\Windows\System32\spool\PRINTERS\FP00003.SPL`" and "`C:\Windows\System32\spool\PRINTERS\FP00003.SHD`". SPL files are the actual spool (print job) files. SHD files provide information about which printer the print job was sent to and from whom the print job came.

Please note that the service runs under the same account as when running the console app and the printer driver is always the same on all systems. Also, running exactly the same code, but by automating MS-Word to print to the same printer from a service, works fine as well.

I tried to explain the problem and please feel free to ask clarification through comments.

Here is the code used in Windows service and console app:

```
//** Create inforpath application instance
Microsoft.Office.Interop.InfoPath.Application app = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.InfoPath.Application();
//** Open XML file
XDocument xdoc = app.XDocuments.Open(@"F:\InfoPathTestFiles\8f2de6cb86594203b5ecb301cb2f4a94.xml", 1);
//** give enough time for infopath.exe to open the XML file
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);
//** Send print command.
xdoc.PrintOut();
//** let it cool for 5 seconds.
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);
//** quit the application.
app.Quit(true);
```

Please note that the InfoPath file (xml) needs to be fully trusted in order for it to print in this manner.

Comment: Never, never, never print from a service.  You cannot see an error dialog displayed by a printer driver.

Comment: We have created a custom printer to print to a port and port name points to a file. When request sent to this printer, it creates a file at a specified folder. Also, custom printer is set as default printer. It works when you .PrintOut() using console app and it does not work using the service. I agree with Hans that you cannot see the error dialog, but the document I am printing is very simple one and there is no error when printed.